# Make Change in Linear Time

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, dynamic-programming, combinatorics

The question is motivated by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67452706/number-of-ways-to-change-coins-in-constant-time) on StackOverflow.

Given an integer $n$ and a finite list of distinct positive integers $ds$, let $f(n, ds)$ denote the number of ways $n$ can be expressed as a sum of elements of $ds$ up to order. Sometimes $f(n, ds)$ is referred to as the number of ways to make change of $n$ in terms of coins with denominations $ds$. For example:

- $f(1, [1]) = 1$
- $f(2, [1, 2]) = 2$
- $f(100, [1, 2]) = 51$
- $f(5, [1, 2, 5]) = 4$
- $f(27, [1, 5, 10]) = 12$
- $f(7, [3, 5]) = 0$

Question: is it possible to compute $f(n, ds)$ in $O(\operatorname{length}(ds))$ time if integer operations take constant time, e.g. $a \bmod b$ can be computed in $O(1)$?

Comment: I think [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/coin-change-dp-7/) or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243831/how-to-count-possible-combination-for-coin-problem) could help.
It seems solutions are at best in $O(n|ds|)$.

Comment: There are "lists of integers" where the greedy algorithm can be proven optimal. en.wikipedia refers to Pearson, David: *A polynomial-time algorithm for the change-making problem*, OR Letters 33 (2005).